# Where are all my Java VMs installed in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

In my Ubuntu 8.04 'Other' menu, it has 'OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime', 'Sun Java 5.0 Runtime' , 'Sun Java 6 Runtime'.

Can you please tell me where are these actually installed?
I can only fine 1, the OpenJDK :

$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK  Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_0-b11)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 1.6.0_0-b11, mixed mode)

How can I find the others?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try in terminal `whereis java`

It is probably a simlink located in `/usr/bin`, you can check what real file is the simlink pointing to easily, for example using ls:

`ls -l /usr/bin/java`

Answer (score 1):

Most modern Linux distros uses `update-alternatives` to manage the various java installations. You can see which ones are currently available with:

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

And change the active alternative with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

See `man 8 update-alternatives` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the files belonging to a package with

```
dpkg-query --listfiles PACKAGE
```

The package name might be sun-java6-jdk or sun-java6-bin. But you can easily find out the package name with synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

I forget exactly on Ubuntu, I think they get stuck in either /usr/java or /usr/lib/java, at any rate, `locate java|grep usr` should give you an idea of where it's at.

Answer (score 0):

The jre/jdk's are always installed under `/usr/jvm`.   libraries (jar files) for extra packages are installed in `/usr/share/java`.